# Two questions about proofs of certain properties of $(\mathbb Z_n, +_n, *_n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

1. Addition in $\mathbb Z_n$ is defined as $a +_n b = a + b \operatorname{mod} n$. Here below is a proof of the fact that $+_n$ is associative:

> Since $\mathbb Z_n$ is closed under $+_n, \ a +_n (b +_n c) \in \mathbb Z_n$. Now $a +_n (b +_n c) = a +_n ((b + c) \operatorname{mod} n) = a +_n (b + c - nq) = a +_n (b + c + n(-q)) = (a + (b + c + n(-q))) + n(-j) = (a + b + c) + n(-j - q) = (a + b + c) + ns.$
>
> We have $a + b + c + ns \equiv a + b + c \pmod n.$
>
> Then $a + b + c \operatorname{mod} n = \color{red}{a + b + c + ns \operatorname{mod} n = a + b + c + ns}.$
>
> Thus $a +_n (b +_n c) = a + b + c \operatorname{mod} n$. By a similar argument, $(a +_n b) +_n c = a + b + c \operatorname{mod} n$.

I am not sure how they got the part in red above. The function $\operatorname{mod}$ is a remainder operator and so $a + b + c + ns$ must be the remainder of $a + b + c + ns$ when divided by $n$. Would the following work to show the part in red holds:

Any integer divides zero $ \implies 0 = nq \implies (a + b + c + ns) = nq + (a + b + c + ns) \implies a + b + c + ns \operatorname{mod} n = a + b + c + ns?$

2. If we also define subtraction in $\mathbb Z_n$ by analogy with $+_n$ as $a -_n b = a - b\operatorname{mod} n$, would showing $a = b +_n (a -_n b)$ prove $-_n$ is well-defined? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see why the part in red is even true. By definition, the quantity $a + b + c + ns \operatorname{\, (mod } n)$ is the least non-negative residue of $a + b + c + ns$ modulo $n,$ and this cannot possibly be $a + b + c + ns.$

Comment: For the well-definedness of subtraction modulo $n,$ you must show that the difference of the congruence classes of $a$ and $b$ modulo $n$ is equal to the congruence class of the difference of $a$ and $b.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fail to understand the given proof that addition modulo $n$ is associative, but here is an alternative proof.

**Proof.** We claim that $a + (b + c) \equiv (a + b) + c \operatorname{\, (mod } n).$ By the Division Algorithm, there exist integers $q$ and $0 \leq r \leq n - 1$ such that $a + (b + c) = nq + r.$ Considering that addition of integers is associative, we have that $(a + b) + c = nq + r.$ We conclude therefore that $a + (b + c) - nq = r = (a + b) + c$ so that $a + (b + c) \equiv (a + b) + c \operatorname{\, (mod } n).$ QED.

One could also appeal to the fact that $a + (b + c) = (a + b) + c$ so that $n \,|\, ([a + (b + c)] - [(a + b) + c]).$

Proving that subtraction modulo $n$ is well-defined goes as follows.

**Proof.** We claim that if $a \equiv b \operatorname{\, (mod } n)$ and $c \equiv d \operatorname{\, (mod } n),$ then $a - c \equiv b - d \operatorname{\, (mod } n).$ By the Division Algorithm, there exist integers $p$ and $q$ such that  $a = np + b$ and $c = nq + d.$ Consequently, we have that $a - c = (np + b) - (nq + d) = (np - nq) + (b - d) = n(p - q) + (b - d).$ Considering therefore that $n \,|\, [(a - c) - (b - d)],$ we conclude that $a - c \equiv b - d \operatorname{\, (mod } n),$ as desired. QED.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $n>0.$ With $x=(a+_nb)+_nc$ and $y=a+_n(b+_nc).$

There exist integers $s,t$ with $x=a+b+c+ns$ and $y=a+b+c+nt.$ So $x-y=n(s-t).$

But $x,y$ belong to $A=\{0,...,n-1\}$ so $|x-y|\le \max A-\min A=n-1.$ So $|n(s-t)|\le n-1.$

So the non-negative integer $|s-t|\le (n-1)/n<1.$ So $|s-t|=0.$ So $s=t.$ So $x=y.$